# Adicionar elementos em um vetor usando loops e inputs

Tags: r

Tentei escrever um comando simples em `R` onde o programa pergunta 5 números para o usuário (input) e adiciona cada um em uma lista. O problema é que o vetor fica vazio. Já tentei com listas também.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
a <- c()

for(numero in 1:5){
  num <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = 'Numero: '))
  append(a,num)
}

print(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
vetor <- rep(NA, 5)

for (indice in seq_along(vetor)) {
  vetor[indice] <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = 'Numero: '))
}

print(vetor)
```

É uma boa prática em R não criar objetos que expandem de tamanho; é melhor criar o objeto já com o tamanho final e usar indexação para preenchê-lo.

Comment: E se eu não sei à priori quantos dados eu vou armazenar no vetor? Por exemplo, vamos supor que eu vá filtrar todas as médias com tamanho maio que 15 de um determinado vetor mas eu não sei quantas são a priori? Nesse caso a única forma que eu vejo de armazenar esses valores maiores que 15 é adicionando-os em um vetor. Não sei se é porque eu estou mais acostumado com Python onde é comum adicionar elementos em listas, mas meu raciocínio é esse.

Comment: Esse é um tópico muito longo para ser respondido aqui. Se lê inglês, veja o capítulo 2 do [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/). Aproveite e leia o capítulo 3, pois também é bom evitar *loops* no R. Bem, leia o livro todo, que é excelente.

Answer (score 3):

```
a <- c()

for(numero in 1:5){
  a <- append(a,numero)
}

print(a)
```

-Você tem que armazenar o vetor dentro de algum lugar quando está executando o "append". A função dá um retorno, esse retorno precisa ser armazenado em algum lugar.

Comment: Nesse caso o que eu gostaria de fazer é diferente. Gostaria de adicionar 5 números digitados pelo usuário na lista, e não simplesmente número de 1 a 5

Comment: Acabei de conseguir inserir o input e adicionar elementos ao vetor, desconsidere a pergunta anterior, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira sem ciclos `for` é ler de `stdin()` com a função `scan`. Basta passar o total de números a ler no argumento `n`.

```
a <- scan(stdin(), what = character(), n = 5, quiet = TRUE)
a <- as.numeric(a)
print(a)
```

Note-se que `scan` lê *números* se o argumento `what` não alterar isso. O problema é que se o usuário se enganar e teclar algo não numérico o `scan` termina com erro. Se forem lidos carateres e depois transformados em numeros esse erro já não ocorre.